# Spring repository how to get list of variables

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

I have Employee and Employer classes.

e.g. **Employer**:

```
List<Employee> employees;
```

How in EmployerRepository extending JpaRepository,
i can write a custom method for retrieving a list of employees ?

like this:

```
List<Employee> findEmployees(int id);
```

But findEmployees() is not working (Jpa can not recognize for what is this method and is throwing a compile error)

Comment: it should be like `findByEmployeeId(int id)` how does your Employee class look like?

Comment: Can you post the error message ?

Comment: No property findEmployees found for type Employer!

Comment: Does Employee have a reference to Employer?